# Retrieve both current and previous elements using Iterator in Java

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I have an ArrayList in my Java code and I would like to retrieve both its current and previous elements.

This is the code I made :

```
    List<Graph> graphs = new ArrayList<Graph>();
    graphs.addAll(bestGraphs.values());
    ListIterator<Graph> listItr = graphs.listIterator();
    while(listItr.hasNext()) {
        if(!listItr.hasPrevious()) {
            listItr.next();
        } else {
            Graph g1 = listItr.previous();
            Graph g2 = listItr.next();
            croisementGraphs(g1, g2);
            listItr.next();
        }
    }
```

`croisementGraphs(g1, g2);` is a function that should take both the current and the previous elements (graphs) of the ArrayList.

The problem here is that both variables `g1` and `g2` point to the same element.

When I read the Javadoc related to the `previous()` function, it says :

> (Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)

What should I do in this case ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to use an `Iterator`, keep a reference to the original element. Or don't use an iterator. Just use a `for` statement with appropriate indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your solution, just take the actual next item:

```
Graph g1 = listItr.previous();
listItr.next();
Graph g2 = listItr.next();
croisementGraphs(g1, g2);
```

And I think that you should read about the iterators, I am afraid you don't understand how they work. I'll try to explain it briefly:

- Iterators are located between items, not at them
- When `next` or `previous` is called iterators return an item they just "walked over"

Small example: lets take a list of a few items: `[1,2,3]`, and present it in the next form: `[.1.2.3.]`, lets show where iterator is by placing a letter `x` there. Now some actions and corresponding state changes:

```
ListIterator x = list.listIterator(); // [x1.2.3.] 
x.next(); // [.1x2.3.], returns 1
x.previous(); // [x1.2.3.], returns 1
x.next(); // [.1x2.3.], returns 1
x.next(); // [.1.2x3.], returns 2
```

Comment: So that is why it returns the same element when calling `previous` and `next` one after the other! Thanks bro! You're a good teacher!

Answer (score 1):

Calling previous moves the position of the ListIterator backwards. Hence you need to consider what position you are at.

Consider you're at position N, you call previous and it will return N and move to N-1, then you call next and it returns N and moves the pointer to it..

Hence you need to call:
    graphs.get(listItr.previousIndex());

if you want it not to move the position of the listIterator.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `listItr.next();` twice like this:

```
    while(listItr.hasNext()) {
    if(!listItr.hasPrevious()) {
        listItr.next();
        listItr.next();
    } else {
        ...
    }
```

For more info go in [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#next%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reduction:

```
graphs.stream().reduce((g1, g2) -> {croisementGraphs(g1, g2); return g2;});
```

If you made `croisementGraphs()` return its second parameter, you could just:

```
graphs.stream().reduce(this::croisementGraphs);
```